# how to get clicked item in my another page

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, windows-10-universal

### My Book class

```
 public class Book{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string BookCover{ get; set; }

 }

public class Bookmanager
{
    public static List<Book> GetBook()
    {
        var BookID= new List<Book>();

        BookID.Add(new Book{ Title = "fruits", BookCover= "Assets/1.jpg" });
        BookID.Add(new Book{ Title = "food", BookCover= "Assets/2.jpeg" });

        return BookID;
    }
}
```

### My mainpage xaml

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind BookID}" Margin="0,0,49,121" 
              ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True" >
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Book">
                <Grid Height="186" Width="155">
                    <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{x:Bind <GridView     ItemsSource="{x:Bind BookCover}" Margin="0,0,49,121" 
              ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True" >
                </grid>
           </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

### XAML.cs

Here is my source code in XAML.cs I have written the code to navigate to my image **so what code should I write in my ItemPage to retrieve my BookCover image.** Help me please I'm new here!

```
private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var Mybooks= ((Book)e.ClickedItem).BookCover;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemPage), Mybooks);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Page class have implemented the interface IPageOverrides.
So You just need to override it in your ItemPage like below:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ////this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemPage), Mybooks);
    //e.Parameter is Mybooks.
}
```